# How to ng serve and npm start together?

Tags: node.js, angular

This MEAN [sample](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/MEAN-bucketlist-application), `ng serve` starts the app fine at port 4200 but can't fetch data as Fiddler shows it fails calling an API at port 3000.

[image]

How to start npm alongside ng?

/package.json

```
"name": "awesome-bucketlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple bucketlist app using MEAN stack",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  }
```

/angular-src/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-src",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

launch.json

```
{
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/bucketlist",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json, you can chain commands together using `&&`.

Ex:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./some_script_to_start_angular.sh && node app"
}
```

Comment: what is .sh file?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I finally realized having both Api and UI in the same folder/project/solution is not practical. An API is not specific to an UI, it's a universal DLL/service, should be siting somewhere by itself. So I separated them into two diff folders and have 2 VSC instances to run them:

1. start the API in debug mode
2. in 2nd VSC, run `ng serve` and let it take time to build, when "Compiled successfully" go to launch.json to start the debug entry associated with Chrome
   they work perfectly.